# Tab bar View Controller in Xcode 7

Tags: tabs, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, ios9

Hi I Have a tab bar view controller which is the initial view controller . Now I have 5 tabs in that tab bar view controller. Now How do I show 3rd tab by default when the app runs for the first time . by default the first tab is shown  . how do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in app delegate appfinishedLaunching method end (once all the tab bar is set up if you are doing programmatically) programmatically select the tab bar index

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```